# Inverse kinematics offset?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem with my rig. As I put a IK constrain on the two bones, the constrained one is just offsetting as shown in the screenshot below

Is there anything I did wrong?

Best regards

[image]

Comment: Are those bones connected? That would help for a start.